# Base64_encode of Image not Rendering Properly

Tags: php, base64, php-7.2

I'm trying to generate a base64 string, using base64_encode.

```
    private function _returnImgBase64()
    {
        $return = null;

        try {

            $img = file_get_contents(
                'https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/geeksforgeeks-22.png'
            );
            $image64 = base64_encode($img);

            return $image64;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $return = $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

It returns a base64 string, but when I try to [convert it online](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) the image is not correct.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: No issues with your code. I have tried your code and converted it to image from the specified link. It works. Are you sure you copied the complete Base64 String ?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using Harish? Can you post the base64 string?

Comment: Worked fine with PHP 7.4.6 from the command line. The base64 result is too large to add as a comment.

Comment: Use `fopen($filename, "r")` instead of file_get_contents to ensure 100% binary compatibility.

Comment: PHP Version 7.3.5. As @Dave Said, Can't add the Base64 String.

Comment: Thank you guys, I wasn't copying the whole string. Shame on me.